# How can I update a record in before trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I need to check if a record which is getting inserted has a duplicate. If there is one, then change a boolean field (`Is_latest__c`) to true in the inserted record and update the duplicate's field to false. I have created a before insert trigger, and in this trigger I check if a duplicate exists and change the `Is_latest__c` field of the inserted record to true. But when I try to update the old duplicate value in the trigger I am getting error that

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id afdfd9000000hxuSAEAY; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, lastupdate: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id arfg45000000hxuSAEAY; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = artr9000000hxuSA) is currently in trigger lastupdate, therefore it cannot recursively update itself

Is there any solution for this issue?

My code:

```
trigger lastupdate on Visit__c(before insert, before update) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore) {
        visitTriggerHandler vTH = new visitTriggerHandler();
        vTH.beforeInsertTrigger(Trigger.new);
    } 
}

public class visitTriggerHandler {
    public Set<String> contactFieldSet = new Set<String>();
    public Set<String> projectFieldSet = new Set<String>();
    public Set<String> surveyFieldSet = new Set<String>();
    public List<Visit__c> visitList = new List<Visit__c>();
    Map<Id, Visit__c> visitBeforeInsertMap = new Map<Id, Visit__c>();

    public void beforeInsertTrigger(Map<Id, Visit__c> visitBeforeInsertMaps, List<Visit__c> visitBeforeInsertList) {
        for(Visit__c visitToMap : visitBeforeInsertList) {
            visitBeforeInsertMap.put(visitToMap.Id, visitToMap);
        }

        for(Visit__c visit : visitBeforeInsertList) {
            contactFieldSet.add(visit.Contact__c);
            projectFieldSet.add(visit.Project_Group__c);
            surveyFieldSet.add(visit.Survey__c);
        }

        visitList = [SELECT Id FROM Visit__c
                     WHERE Survey__c IN :surveyFieldSet
                     AND Contact__r.Id IN :contactFieldSet
                     AND Project_Group__c IN :projectFieldSet
                     AND Is_latest__c = true];

        if(visitList.size() > 0) {
            for(Visit__c islastUpdate : visitBeforeInsertList) {
                islastUpdate.Is_latest__c = true;
            }
        }

        //visitList.add(islastUpdate);
        visitBeforeInsertList = visitBeforeInsertMap.values();
        //update visitList;
    }
}
```

Comment: this can have different causes. Pls include your code so we can provide the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

In a **before update** you don't need to explicitly call `update` on the records you want to modify. You're working on them before they go into the database, so you simply need to set the field values you want and that's it.

```
trigger smithification on Contact (before insert, before update) {
   if(Trigger.isBefore)
      for(Contact c : Trigger.New)
         c.LastName = 'Smith';
}
```

The above trigger would mean all contacts currently being modified in the system have the last name 'Smith'.

Comment: yes you are right. But here I need to update a old record when new duplicate recode is create it mean only on before insert. So that is way I am getting confused that same time when I insert a record I need  to update to.

Comment: If you're updating an old record, that will then fire the trigger again (as update). You'll want to use a static boolean or similar to prevent the trigger running a second time.

Comment: yes but how can I update a old record in before insert. Because in before insert it is not allowing to update any record which is existing in data base.

Answer (score 3):

First, by definition, all of the records inserted in the before insert trigger should be set to isLatest__c = true

So, your problem is how to set the records with the same value of survey, contact.id, and project_group to isLatest__c = false

I would break up this problem into two triggers - one before insert and one after insert (actually, I would use a trigger framework and just have different handlers for each trigger entry point but that is a longer discussion)

**The before trigger**

```
trigger isLatestUpdate on Visit__c (before insert) {
  for (Visit__c v : Trigger.new) 
     v.isLatest__c = true;  // implicitly sets the value of field in all members of trigger list to true
}
```

**The after trigger**

```
trigger isNoLongerLatestUpdate on Visit__c (after insert) {
 Set<ID> contactIdSet = new Set<ID>();
 Set<String> surveySet = new Set<String>();
 Set<String> projGpSet = new Set<String> ();

 // Step 1 - build sets needed to query other Visits
 for (Visit__c v : Trigger.new)  {
    contactIdSet.add(v.contact__c);
    surveySet.add(v.survey__c);
    projGpSet.add(v.project_group__c);
 }

// Step 2 - query for all other Visits (be sure not to query ourself) with matching survey/contact/proj gp
 List<Visit__c> noLongerLatestVUpdList = new List<Visit__c> ();
 for (Visit__c otherV : [select id, survey__c, contact__c, project_group__c 
                         from Visit__c 
                         where survey__c IN :surveySet and contact__c IN :contactSet and
                           project_group__c IN :projGpSet and id not IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()]) {
    otherV.isLatest__c = false;
    noLongerLatestVUpdList.add(otherV);
 }

// Step 3 - update the no longer latest Visits
 try {
  update noLongerLatestVUpdList ;  // You could also do database.update(noLongerLatestVUpdList ,false) if you want to allow for partial successes in fixing up the old Visit__c
 }
 catch (DmlException e) { // do something useful here including, optionally, rolling back the transaction }
```

*Code was typed in -- might have compile errors*