# Unable to bulkify the trigger for multiple accounts to insert more than 500 records

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, triggercontext

I am writing the trigger which maintains the sequence number in the insertion in various cases. So when I am trying to access this trigger for more than  500 records for multiple accounts it is throwing an error like :--

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 600; first
> error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, ContactTrigger: execution
> of BeforeInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First
> exception on row 0 with id 0035j00000JIEHbAAP;

```
public void beforeInsert(List<Contact> newConTrigger){      
conAcctsIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : newConTrigger){
        System.debug('The c is ' + c);
        conAcctsIdSet.add(c.AccountId);
        
    }
    if(conAcctsIdSet.size()>0){
        conWithAcctsList = [Select Id,(Select Id,AccountId,Sequence_Number__c from Contacts Order By sequence_number__c ASC) from Account where Id IN:conAcctsIdSet];
        for(Account accts: conWithAcctsList){
            conListOld = new List<Contact>();
            con = new List<Contact>();
            conList = new List<Contact>();
            conMap = new Map<Integer,Contact>();
            conList.clear();
            for(Contact c : newConTrigger){
                if(c.AccountId == accts.id){
                    con.add(c);
                }
            }                
            if(accts.contacts.size()>0){
                for(Contact conRec : accts.contacts){
                    conMap.put((Integer)conRec.Sequence_Number__c,conRec);//fillig the with old values
                }
                System.debug('the old cons are ' + accts.contacts);
                conListOld.addAll(accts.contacts);
                System.debug('the conMap is 0'+conMap);
                addRecords(con,accts.id);
                for(Contact c : conMap.values()){
                    if(conListOld.contains(c)){
                        conList.add(c);
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                System.debug('Elsepart');
                addRecords(con,accts.id);
            }
            
            if(conList.size()>0){
                update conList;
            }
        }
    } 
}
public void addRecords(List<Contact> newContacts,Id accId){
    for(Contact c : newContacts){
        Integer val = (Integer)c.Sequence_Number__c;
        System.debug('The new ARe :: ' + newContacts);
        if(accId == c.AccountId && conMap.containsKey(val)){
            for(Integer i = conMap.size()+1;i>val;i--){
                conMap.get(i-1).Sequence_Number__c = i; 
                conMap.put(i,conMap.get(i-1));
            }
            conMap.put((Integer)c.Sequence_Number__c,c);
            c.Sequence_Number__c = conMap.size()+1;
        }
        else{
            conMap.put((Integer)c.Sequence_Number__c , c);
        }
        System.debug('The Map is ::' + conMap);
    }          
}
```

Comment: Is the handler a with or without sharing class? I'm wondering if there's a lack of sharing access to one of the referenced IDs...

Comment: It is with handler

Answer (score 0):

Your “update conList” statement will often include records from the “newConTrigger” variable, which will cause Salesforce to throw an error. The new records are added to the ‘con’ variable, which is delivered to the AddRecords method, which adds them to conMap. There is a loop that adds the conMap values to conList. Then conList is used for the update.

See this link: [Updating Records in before trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57377/how-can-i-update-a-record-in-before-trigger)
and [Record Update in before trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AuaRIAS)

If you just need to edit some values for the inbound records, you can set the attributes in your trigger, and they will be inserted with those values. It is very common for “before” triggers to set default values, and it works without using an DML statement.

Comment: NO! I have used conList only at one place and there I also used a check condition then how conList can contain elements of newConTrigger

Comment: You use newConList to specifically match and add the contacts to "con" which are then passed to addRecords and get updated, so I think this answer is likely correct. Note, also, you use the nested loop anti-pattern to scan the accounts for matches in the contacts. You need to switch to using a map.

Comment: Can You please suggest how can I convert that thing to Map?

Comment: To confirm that records from the trigger are included in the update statement, you can use sets (just for debugging purposes). Code like this will alert you:
```Set<contact toUpdate = new set<contact>(conList);
Set<contact> fromTrigger = new set<contact>(newConTrigger);

Boolean overlap = toUpdate.removeAll(fromTrigger);
If (overlap) {
 System.debug(loggingLevel.warn, ‘OVERLAP FOUND’);
}
```

Comment: No, Records are not  overlapping I have checked by using this .

Comment: First exception on row 200 with id 0035j00000JILkxAAH; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, We can't save this record because the “Salutation” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details
This error is arising again and again please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Yes, Now it is that overlap part is running now how should  I sort that issue any approach?